# Move rows as columns?

Tags: r

I plan to convert below table:

| ym | member_casual | ride_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 Dec | casual | 25 |
| 2021 Dec | member | 42 |
| 2022 Jan | casual | 35 |
| 2022 Jan | member | 55 |

to table as below:

| ym | member | casual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 Dec | 42 | 25 |
| 2022 Jan | 55 | 35 |

**Thanks for your answer**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = member_casual, values_from = ride_count)
```

Which gives:

```
  ym       casual member
  <chr>     <int>  <int>
1 2021 Dec     25     42
2 2022 Jan     35     55
```